# I want to get the information of exact categories from Google Photos API, such as the each people in PEOPLE categories

Tags: google-photos, google-photos-api

I want to get the information of exact categories from Google Photos API, such as the each people in PEOPLE categories ,but I find any methods in Google Photos APIs, Can you help me to get  the information of exact categories?

Comment: You'll need to be more specific about what you're asking for. There's examples of how to use the google-photos api here: 
https://github.com/googlesamples/google-photos/tree/master/REST/PhotoFrame

Comment: This page in particular may be of use to you where they show applying filters on people: https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/apply-filters#content-categories

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to programmatically get a list of categories that you can filter. 
To my knowledge and after having worked with the API for some weeks, this is currently not possible.

There is a static list of categories that you can currently use for filtering at : https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/apply-filters#content-categories

Of course it would be nice of Google to provide a way to get this list dynamically with an API call in case this list is updated/modified in the future.

The Google Photos API is still very new and in beta, so maybe this will be a future feature from Google.